# How to loop through all elements inside a text full of HTML elements using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a constant variable that has full of HTML elements in it and I wanted to loop through all of the elements that can be found in that long text for me to be able to modify some attributes of the elements like the styles listed on every element.

Example of the content of the long text:

```
const longText = <p><b><span style="color: #6d64e8;">Your Company</span></b></p><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">123 Your Street</span></p><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">Your City, ST 12345</span></p><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">(123) 456 - 7890</span></p><p><span style="color: #283592; font-weight: 400;">Product Brochure</span></p><p><span style="color: #e01b84; font-weight: 400;">September 04, 20XX</span></p><h1><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: 400;">Product Overview</span></h1><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span></p><p><b><span style="color: #6d64e8;">Your Company</span></b></p><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">123 Your Street</span></p><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">Your City, ST 12345</span></p><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">(123) 456 - 7890</span></p><p><span style="color: #283592; font-weight: 400;">Product Brochure</span></p><p><span style="color: #e01b84; font-weight: 400;">September 04, 20XX</span></p><h1><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: 400;">Product Overview</span></h1><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span></p>
```

Is there a way for me to do that using Javascript or jQuery?

Like doing `longText.getElementsByTagName('*').forEach((element) => {})`

or `$(longText).each((element) =>{})?`

Comment: `Like doing longText.getElementsByTagName` no, longText is TEXT ... `$(longText).each((element) =>{})?` maybe, but not quite

Comment: you can loop with specific html element like `p`, `div`...not like common HTML element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create an element, add the text as innerHTML, and use `querySelectorAll('*")` and all your elements will be available in one loop

```js
const html = `<p><b><span style="color: #6d64e8;">Your Company</span></b></p><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">123 Your Street</span></p>`;

const el = document.createElement('root'); // name does NOT matter
el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
el.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(el => console.log(el.nodeName, el.textContent));
```

Answer (score 1):

this way:

```js
const longText =
  `<p><b><span style="color: #6d64e8;">Your Company</span></b></p><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">123 Your Street</span></p><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">Your City, ST 12345</span></p><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">(123) 456 - 7890</span></p><p><span style="color: #283592; font-weight: 400;">Product Brochure</span></p><p><span style="color: #e01b84; font-weight: 400;">September 04, 20XX</span></p><h1><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: 400;">Product Overview</span></h1><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span></p><p><b><span style="color: #6d64e8;">Your Company</span></b></p><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">123 Your Street</span></p><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">Your City, ST 12345</span></p><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">(123) 456 - 7890</span></p><p><span style="color: #283592; font-weight: 400;">Product Brochure</span></p><p><span style="color: #e01b84; font-weight: 400;">September 04, 20XX</span></p><h1><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: 400;">Product Overview</span></h1><p><span style="color: #666666; font-weight: 400;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span></p>`


const myDiv = document.createElement('div')

myDiv.innerHTML = longText

myDiv.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(s=>
  {
 // s.style = ....
  console.log(s.textContent)
  })
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```